# MUI: Is there a better way to trap focus within Modal without setInterval?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

#### Context

1. There is a React SPA page. Material-UI v4 library is used.
2. There is a [FullScreen Dialog](https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/#full-screen-dialogs) on it.

#### Performance problem

We noticed that even without user interactions the page consumes some CPU resources. It turned out that Dialog uses `TrapFocus` component under hood, that uses `setInterval` firing every 50ms. There is `disableEnforceFocus` setting for Dialog, though it does not affect interval.

#### Question

Is there a better way to provide same level of accessibility without setting up the 50ms interval? Would an [update to react-focus-lock](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15450) eliminate performance issue?